# How to "understand" (manually interpret) a tiny binary executable written in NASM for Linux

Tags: assembly, nasm, executable, binary-data

Recently i've started learning NASM and I want to go deeper into the theory behind how compilers, VMs and computers generally work. I've written a small and simple NASM program, just to watch what binary code it creates after building it with the NASM compiler.

The ASM code is here:

```
    section .data
            c: db 420

    section .text
            global _start:
            _start:
            mov ecx, 1337

            mov eax, eax
            mov eax, ebx
            mov eax, ecx
            mov eax, edx
            mov eax, ebp
            mov eax, esp

            mov ebx, eax
            mov ebx, ebx
            mov ebx, ecx
            mov ebx, edx
            mov ebx, ebp
            mov ebx, esp

            mov ecx, eax
            mov ecx, ebx
            mov ecx, ecx
            mov ecx, edx
            mov ecx, ebp
            mov ecx, esp

            mov edx, eax
            mov edx, ebx
            mov edx, ecx
            mov edx, edx
            mov edx, ebp
            mov edx, esp


            ; exit
            mov eax, 1
            mov ebx, 2
            int 80h
```

So basically, here i just move every register into every other register. I know that the output will have overloaded 'mov' commands so that a mov with registers looks different than a mov with a register and a constant. The objdump of the program above obviously very simple too:

```
    ./program:     file format elf64-x86-64
    Disassembly of section .text:

    00000000004000b0 <.text>:
    4000b0: b9 39 05 00 00          mov    $0x539,%ecx
    4000b5: 89 c0                   mov    %eax,%eax
    4000b7: 89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
    4000b9: 89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
    4000bb: 89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
    4000bd: 89 e8                   mov    %ebp,%eax
    4000bf: 89 e0                   mov    %esp,%eax

    4000c1: 89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
    4000c3: 89 db                   mov    %ebx,%ebx
    4000c5: 89 cb                   mov    %ecx,%ebx
    4000c7: 89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx
    4000c9: 89 eb                   mov    %ebp,%ebx
    4000cb: 89 e3                   mov    %esp,%ebx

    4000cd: 89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
    4000cf: 89 d9                   mov    %ebx,%ecx
    4000d1: 89 c9                   mov    %ecx,%ecx
    4000d3: 89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
    4000d5: 89 e9                   mov    %ebp,%ecx
    4000d7: 89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx

    4000d9: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
    4000db: 89 da                   mov    %ebx,%edx
    4000dd: 89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
    4000df: 89 d2                   mov    %edx,%edx
    4000e1: 89 ea                   mov    %ebp,%edx
    4000e3: 89 e2                   mov    %esp,%edx


    4000e5: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    4000ea: bb 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%ebx
    4000ef: cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

We can see that the 89 instruction on "0x4000b5" - "0x4000e3" means move register into other register. But what confuses me that the second byte on the instruction line is not what i would excpect to be. How can i interpret this? Did I get something wrong with the "overloading" part?

Thank you all for your time and excuse my bad english please. I try to improve it everytime I can! :)

Comment: You may want to use `objdump -M intel -D file.o` to get something resembling original source more, unless you are actually curious about gas syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You are aware that you don't need to reverse engineer this as it is well documented in the official manuals, right? :) See *Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte* in the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2 (2A, 2B & 2C): Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*.

Note that x86 registers are not numbered in the order you'd expect. The order, for whatever reason, is: `eax`, `ecx`, `edx`, `ebx`, `esp`, `ebp`, `esi`, `edi`.

In the second byte, which is called *modr/m*, bits #0-2 and #3-5 are used for encoding register operands. This isn't immediately obvious in hex, but would be in octal. Some examples:

```
211 300 mov %eax,%eax ; move from register #0 to #0
211 330 mov %ebx,%eax ; move from register #3 to #0
211 313 mov %ecx,%ebx ; move from register #1 to #3
```